# while adding web part zone using SP Designer nothing has been added to page layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, office-365-developer

I am trying to add web part zone to new page layout template using SP Designer but after clicking on button "Web Part Zone" nothing is happening.

fyi
I have migrated site from SP 2010 to SP Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add web part zone in other site which is not migrated from SharePoint 2010?

Try to add the following snippet:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="TestZone1" ID="TestZone1">
<ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Add web part zone in custom page layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126449/add-web-part-zone-in-custom-page-layout)

Comment: i tried this before posting but wasn't working as expected. But after started working automatically.